# Java "cannot find symbol- variable totAMTpizza'

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to make a simple program in java by *BlueJ*. But while compiling it gives me a error that "**cannot find symbol- variable totAMTpizza**". Anyone with the fix.

[image]

Comment: you should copy & paste the code not a screen shot.

Comment: where are you using that variable? it looks like its only defined in those if statements, and used nowhere else.

Comment: Wrong way to make a question, however have a look at how variables are scoped in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a variable inside an `if` block, it's only visible inside that block. In your program you declare the `totAMTpizza` variable inside the three `if` and `else if` blocks, so it's not visible outside of those three blocks.

The fix is to move the declaration to the outside.

```
int pizzaQTY = input.nextInt();
int totAMTpizza;

System.out.printf('\f');

if (pizzaSize == 1) {
    int pizzaSmall = 120;
    totAMTpizza = pizzaSmall * pizzaQTY;
}
else if (pizzaSize == 2) {
    ...
}
else if (pizzaSize == 3) {
    ...
}
```

For what it's worth, you could move the calculation for `totAMTpizza` after the if/else conditions so you don't repeat yourself.

```
int pizzaQTY = input.nextInt();
int pizzaCost;

if (pizzaSize == 1) {
    pizzaCost = 120;
}
else if (pizzaSize == 2) {
    pizzaCost = 140;
}
else if (pizzaSize == 3) {
    pizzaCost = 160;
}

int totAMTpizza = pizzaQTY * pizzaCost;
```